# "Unable to find a route to match the URI: xxxxx/index.php"

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I'm trying to use an old project in localhost, its based on kohana 3.1.1.1

When I try to enter to index.php I get:
"Unable to find a route to match the URI: [project name]/index.php"

Im a noob using frameworks but I know PHP. Is there a way I can solve it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You need make changes in 2 files:

- `.htaccess`
- `application/bootstrap`, [Kohana::init section](http://kohana.top/3.1/guide/kohana/bootstrap)

```php
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url' => '/kohana/',
    'index_file' => false,
));
```